# Difference between r+b and rb+ (or w+b and wb+)

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

While reading or writing to file in binary mode, what's the difference between putting '+' between 'r'/'w' and 'b' or putting it right after them both?

I searched and i foud that this affects the behavoir of reading/writing to the file but i don't understand what that means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.21.5.3 The fopen function)

> **r+b** or **rb+** open binary file for update (reading and writing)

So there is no difference in specifying the mode.

Here are some other equivalent mode specifications

> **w+b** or **wb+** truncate to zero length or create binary file for update
>
> **w+bx** or **wb+x** create binary file for update
>
> **a+b** or **ab+** append; open or create binary file for update, writing at end-of-file

Comment: Note that the `x` is specified in optional [Annex K](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.2.1) of the C11  (C17, C18) standard — not all standard implementations support it.